# React navigation withNavigation HOC not working in carousel

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm making a react-native app using expo I'm using the snap-in-carousel library

I want when someone click on the carousel it navigate here is the code

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { withNavigation } from 'react-navigation';

export default class SliderEntry extends Component {

    static propTypes = {
        data: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
        even: PropTypes.bool,
        parallax: PropTypes.bool,
        parallaxProps: PropTypes.object
    };

    get image () {
        const { data: { illustration }, parallax, parallaxProps, even } = this.props;

        return parallax ? (
            <ParallaxImage
              source={{ uri: illustration }}
              containerStyle={[styles.imageContainer, even ? styles.imageContainerEven : {}]}
              style={styles.image}
              parallaxFactor={0.35}
              showSpinner={true}
              spinnerColor={even ? 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4)' : 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25)'}
              {...parallaxProps}
            />
        ) : (
            <Image
              source={{ uri: illustration }}
              style={styles.image}
            />
        );
    }

    render () {

        const { data: { title, subtitle}, even, navigation } = this.props;    

        const uppercaseTitle = title ? (
            <Text
              style={[styles.title, even ? styles.titleEven : {}]}
              numberOfLines={2}
            >
                { title.toUpperCase() }
            </Text>
        ) : false;

        return (
            <TouchableOpacity
              activeOpacity={1}
              style={styles.slideInnerContainer}
              onPress={() => navigation.push('ProfileScreen', {category: title })}  
              >
                <View style={styles.shadow} />
                <View style={[styles.imageContainer, even ? styles.imageContainerEven : {}]}>
                    { this.image }
                    <View style={[styles.radiusMask, even ? styles.radiusMaskEven : {}]} />
                </View>
                <View style={[styles.textContainer, even ? styles.textContainerEven : {}]}>
                    { uppercaseTitle }
                    <Text
                      style={[styles.subtitle, even ? styles.subtitleEven : {}]}
                      numberOfLines={2}
                    >
                        { subtitle }
                    </Text>
                </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        );
    }
}
```

i get undefined is not an object (evaluating 'navigation.push')

here is a link to the project on Github: https://github.com/Ov3rControl/Weddi 
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not actually using withNavigation, you're just importing it. You need to pass your component class into the withNavigation HOC.

The way withNavigation works is, you pass in your component, and withNavigation adds the navigation object as a prop to your component.

You're not doing that, hence why this.props.navigation is undefined.

See your modified code below, the export default expression has moved to the bottom, being passed withNavigation(SliderEntry).

Read the manual. https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/with-navigation.html

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { withNavigation } from 'react-navigation';

class SliderEntry extends Component {

    static propTypes = {
        data: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
        even: PropTypes.bool,
        parallax: PropTypes.bool,
        parallaxProps: PropTypes.object
    };

    get image () {
        const { data: { illustration }, parallax, parallaxProps, even } = this.props;

        return parallax ? (
            <ParallaxImage
              source={{ uri: illustration }}
              containerStyle={[styles.imageContainer, even ? styles.imageContainerEven : {}]}
              style={styles.image}
              parallaxFactor={0.35}
              showSpinner={true}
              spinnerColor={even ? 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4)' : 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25)'}
              {...parallaxProps}
            />
        ) : (
            <Image
              source={{ uri: illustration }}
              style={styles.image}
            />
        );
    }

    render () {

        const { data: { title, subtitle}, even, navigation } = this.props;    

        const uppercaseTitle = title ? (
            <Text
              style={[styles.title, even ? styles.titleEven : {}]}
              numberOfLines={2}
            >
                { title.toUpperCase() }
            </Text>
        ) : false;

        return (
            <TouchableOpacity
              activeOpacity={1}
              style={styles.slideInnerContainer}
              onPress={() => navigation.push('ProfileScreen', {category: title })}  
              >
                <View style={styles.shadow} />
                <View style={[styles.imageContainer, even ? styles.imageContainerEven : {}]}>
                    { this.image }
                    <View style={[styles.radiusMask, even ? styles.radiusMaskEven : {}]} />
                </View>
                <View style={[styles.textContainer, even ? styles.textContainerEven : {}]}>
                    { uppercaseTitle }
                    <Text
                      style={[styles.subtitle, even ? styles.subtitleEven : {}]}
                      numberOfLines={2}
                    >
                        { subtitle }
                    </Text>
                </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        );
    }
}

// See the component is being wrapped with withNavigation.
export default withNavigation(SliderEntry);
```

Comment: Thanks Man Works just fine. Awesome